# Django Haystack searching times between and displaying only ForeignKey results

Tags: django, postgresql, django-haystack

I have model Time, which contains time for one date. Then I have object Person, which is ForeginKey field in Time model. I'm indexing Time objects to find out if Person has times in given time space.

I tried to add this to index, but when indexing, I get error:

```
def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return self.get_model().objects.all().distinct('person')
```

Error:

```
DatabaseError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

So I want only display persons, not times, but I think I have to index times, so I can get persons who have times between given date interval.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're trying to achive. Could you expand  a little and also share a little more of your code? How does your models.py look like? Where does the method go? Why do you need Time to be a different model and not a field for 'person'? How would you like the query search result to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself. For some reason method build_queryset overrided order_by clause, so I had to override build_queryset, see return where I commented order_by clause.

Here is methods I put in my index class:

```
def build_queryset(self, using=None, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    """
    Get the default QuerySet to index when doing an index update.

    Subclasses can override this method to take into account related
    model modification times.

    The default is to use ``SearchIndex.index_queryset`` and filter
    based on ``SearchIndex.get_updated_field``
    """
    extra_lookup_kwargs = {}
    model = self.get_model()
    updated_field = self.get_updated_field()

    update_field_msg = ("No updated date field found for '%s' "
                        "- not restricting by age.") % model.__name__

    if start_date:
        if updated_field:
            extra_lookup_kwargs['%s__gte' % updated_field] = start_date
        else:
            warnings.warn(update_field_msg)

    if end_date:
        if updated_field:
            extra_lookup_kwargs['%s__lte' % updated_field] = end_date
        else:
            warnings.warn(update_field_msg)

    index_qs = None

    if hasattr(self, 'get_queryset'):
        warnings.warn("'SearchIndex.get_queryset' was deprecated in Haystack v2. Please rename the method 'index_queryset'.")
        index_qs = self.get_queryset()
    else:
        index_qs = self.index_queryset(using=using)

    if not hasattr(index_qs, 'filter'):
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("The '%r' class must return a 'QuerySet' in the 'index_queryset' method." % self)

    # `.select_related()` seems like a good idea here but can fail on
    # nullable `ForeignKey` as well as what seems like other cases.
    return index_qs.filter(**extra_lookup_kwargs)#.order_by(model._meta.pk.name)

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return self.get_model().objects.all().distinct('person').order_by('person')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return self.get_model().objects.all().order_by('person').distinct('person')
```